# Get Specific InflatedView Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

This is my `item_simple_itemview.xml`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/simple_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:text="Test"
        android:text="This is some temp text" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="208dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:minWidth="10dip"
        android:minHeight="10dip"
        android:onClick="onChangeClick" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I've created a `RecyclerView` with multiple instances of this xml file, as they are "items" in the list.

My `onChangeClick` is as follows:

```
public void onChangeClick(View view) {
        View inflatedView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_simple_itemview, null);

        TextView textView = inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.simple_text);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), (CharSequence) ("Text: " + textView.getText()), 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
}
```

I programatically add instances of `item_simple_itemview`s to the `RecyclerView`, and change the text in `simple_text` and `btn`. When I click the button on an individual item's button, though, I get the Toast notification `Text: this is some temp text`.

How do I make the text refer to that specific instance of the item and not the base xml file itself?

Comment: Remove `android:onClick="onChangeClick"`. Add an `OnClickListener` to each `Button` as part of your `onBindViewHolder()` implementation that references the `position` passed into `onBindViewHolder()`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you, that works! If you want to put it as a response I'll accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`android:onClick`, as you are using it, is *ancient*. Yours is the second time that I have seen it today, after having not seen it used in years.
In particular, `android:onClick` routes the click event to a method that you implement on your `Activity`. That is not particularly flexible.

And, in your case, if you have N buttons, each of those N buttons will call the same method. While you get the `View` passed into your method as a parameter, that isn't necessarily all that helpful for identifying which row in your `RecyclerView` is the one that was clicked.

I recommend removing `android:onClick`. Instead, in `onBindViewHolder()`, as part of your work, call `setOnItemClickListener()` on the `Button`. The `OnClickListener` (or lambda expression) that you use there can refer to the `position` parameter passed into `onBindViewHolder()`, if you make `position` be `final`. That way, your click handler has direct access to the `position`, and from there you can find out what particular item in the list that `position` corresponds to.